# How do I filter a table by any matching code/name and not every available field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do the following: I have a table populated with data from the DB. Apart from that, I have an input where you can write something and a button that will filter, only showing the lines that have that string. This is working now!

The thing is, the input should only allow you to filter by `foo.name/foo.code` (two propertys of my entity).

I'm adding the code I have in case anyone can guide me out, I've tried several things but this are my first experiences with JQuery while I have a strict story-delivery time. Thanks everyone!

```js
<tbody>
    <c:forEach var="foo" items="${foo}">    
        <tr id = "fooInformation" class="mtrow">
            <th id="fooName" scope="row">${foo.name}</th>
            <td id="fooCode" class="left-align-text">${foo.code}</td>       
            <td class="left-align-text">${foo.country}</td>
            <td class="left-align-text">${foo.region}</td>
            <td class="left-align-text">${foo.subregion}</td>  
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</tbody>
    
$("#search").click(function () { -> button id
    var value = $("#fooRegionSearch").val(); -> value of the input
    var rows = $("#fooRegionTable").find("tr"); -> table id
    rows.hide();
    rows.filter(":contains('" + value + "')").show();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start with, your HTML is invalid - there cannot be elemenets with duplicate IDs in HTML. Use classes instead of IDs.

Then, you need to identify which TRs pass the test. `.filter` can accept a callback, so pass it a function which, given a TR, selects its `fooName` and `fooCode` children which contain the `value` using the [`:contains`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) jQuery selector:

```js
$("#search").click(function() {
  var value = $("#fooRegionSearch").val();
  var rows = $("#fooRegionTable").find("tr");
  rows.hide();
  rows.filter(
    (_, row) => $(row).find('.fooName, .fooCode').filter(`:contains('${value}')`).length
  ).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="fooRegionTable">
  <tr id="fooInformation" class="mtrow">
    <th class="fooName" scope="row">name1</th>
    <td class="fooCode" class="left-align-text">code1</td>
    <td class="left-align-text">${foo.country}</td>
    <td class="left-align-text">${foo.region}</td>
    <td class="left-align-text">${foo.subregion}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="fooInformation" class="mtrow">
    <th class="fooName" scope="row">name2</th>
    <td class="fooCode" class="left-align-text">code2</td>
    <td class="left-align-text">${foo.country}</td>
    <td class="left-align-text">${foo.region}</td>
    <td class="left-align-text">${foo.subregion}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="search">click</button><input id="fooRegionSearch" />
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. Could you clarify where is the double ID? Though it must be a copy paste error as in my code it's working as expected.

Apart from that, I'm actually tying the first solution... I've added a class to the requiered rows. And now my jquery looks like what I've first posted, but the filter is like this: rows.filter("#fooName:contains('" + value + "'), #fooCode:contains('" + value + "')").show();
And it only hides the rows, but no rows show up... Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: You have a `c:forEach`: you're creating multiple `tr`s, right? The table isn't composed of just a single TR. So, the rendered HTML in your original code will contain lots of duplicate IDs.

Comment: Oh yeah I get it now, thanks for the explanation. Regarding your proposed fix, I've tried both versions but the rows are just not showing up. At least the first solution (which I understand more than the second) looks like it should work, do you have any idea why this could be?

Comment: Oh, I see the issue, you're filtering the TRs, but you need to get down to the individual TDs to identify which ones pass the test. The `.filter('.fooName` etc won't work because the TR being filtered isn't a `.fooName` - the TR is a parent. See edit.

Comment: I've accepted the answer but after testing seems it's not working on IE, any idea why? IE is the worst

Comment: Generally, if you have a big script that you need to make compatible with IE, the best solution is to use Babel to transpile down to ES5 automatically. You can also do it manually by replacing all ES2015+ syntax with ES5 syntax, but that's really tedious and a waste of time for anything that isn't trivially small